# rails milia current_tenant usage in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using milia gem;
how can I see `current_tenant.name` in all views without adding it to every controller action?

kind of like see devise `current_user` in all models

Comment: You can create your own helper method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like these way...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_tenant

  def current_tenant
   # Your tenant code here
  end
end
```

Comment: I would write `  @tenant = Tenant.current_tenant` in the def, but how to access it ? gives me errors